# .slidetoggle() sliding up immediately after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some simple jQuery code that slides down an element with the click event of another element using the `.slideToggle()` function:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#search_link").on('click', tapHandler);

  function tapHandler(event) {
    $('#search-div').slideToggle();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#search-text').focus().tap();
    }, 0);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" tabindex="3" id="search_link">Search</a>

<div id="search-div">
  <input type="search" />
</div>
```

On here this code works, however for some reason on my website it slides up immediately after clicking. What can cause this problem? [Here is my site](http://mihalko.eu/?view=mobile), please click on search icon to reproduce the error.

**UPDATE:**

I think the problem is with the jquery.mmenu. If I remove this part:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").mmenu({
       "extensions": [
          "pageshadow"
       ],
       "header": {
              "title": "Menu",
              "add": true,
              "update": true
           }
    });
 });
```

It's immediately start working.

Comment: what does `.tap()` do ? Everything works ok without the `.tap()` function

Comment: @cenanozen I removed the .tap() function but here is still wrong. :(

Comment: Its working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/mgfwejt8/ so it looks like you must have something else going on

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9m2qfdwg/

Comment: You have another event handler in your code. Running the above code from the console works as expected. You should remove the other event handlers

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors showing on your page? Sometimes I find that it's because you haven't closed a function, or you have one too many close function brackets (`}`) or something. Do you have `slideToggle` anywhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct and shouldnt cause an issue as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/mgfwejt8

```
         $(function() {

  $("#search_link").on('click', tapHandler);

  function tapHandler( event ) {
    $('#search-div').slideToggle();
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('#search-text').focus().tap();
    },0);
  }

});
```

Your problem seems reside within this file

catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js

If you remove this file your function works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how it works currently, it seems as though you have two listeners on the same object. Is your code duplicated somewhere?

```js
$(function () {
    $("#search_link").on('click', tapHandler);
    function tapHandler(event) {
        $('#search-div').slideToggle();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#search-text').focus().tap();
        }, 0);
    }
    
    $("#search_link").on('click', tapHandler2);
    function tapHandler2(event) {
        $('#search-div').slideToggle();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#search-text').focus().tap();
        }, 0);
    }

});
```

```css
#search-div {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" tabindex="3" id="search_link">Search</a>

<div id="search-div">
    <input type="search" />
</div>
```

In fact, it has to be running twice. If I type this into the console of your website:

```
$('#search_link').off('click');
$('#search_link').on('click', function(event){
    $('#search-div').slideToggle();
});
```

It all magically works...

Comment: @Kalish It happens. I always double check just before and just after I give an answer. Just in case someone submitted one while I was typing.

Answer (score -1):

The following is a snippet from [.slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) api modified to mimic your code. Try simulating the example, omitting other operations first to see if that does what you intend to do. Hope this helps.

```js
 $("#search_link").click(function(event){
   $('#search-div').slideToggle();
 });
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="search_link">search link</button>

<div id="search-div">
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em>...
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/ - _"This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`"_

Comment: oh yes Jamie Barker, I was trying to refer to example provided in api in the snippet. So just to start off by reducing the context to debug. By eye, I wasnt able to tell immediately.